# Overloading the "=" operator or Conversion Constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement a BigInteger class using C++. Currently my implementation looks like this.

```
#define HEX_SIZE 65536
#define MAX_SLOT 65535
#define BASE 16

template <int T>
class BigInt
{
 std::vector<uint16_t> digits;

    BigInt<T>(unsigned int c)
    {
        unsigned int initSize = T/BASE;
        unsigned int diff =c % HEX_SIZE;
        
        if(diff== 0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<initSize-1;i++)
            {
                this->digits.push_back(0);
            }
            this->digits.push_back(c);

        }else{
            int store = (c - diff)/HEX_SIZE;
            for(int i=0;i<initSize-2;i++)
            {
                this->digits.push_back(0);
            }
            this->digits.push_back(store);
            this->digits.push_back(c);
        }
    }//32 bit unsigned int parameter.
}
```

I'd like it to be able to convert smaller numbers to larger ones, something like this.

```
BigInt <512> A (25);
BigInt <1024> B = A;
```

I'm very new to OOP and C++, reading around I've seen that overloading the = operator is an option, however I've also seen something called a conversion constructor recommended to implement this functionality. Not sure which to try and implement or even how.

Comment: You'll need both, the constructor for `BigInt <1024> B = A;` and the assignment operator for `BigInt <1024> B; B = A;`

Comment: I would reconsider whether you really want `T` as a template parameter (when anyhow it only has an effect at runtime). If `BigInt`s of different size are all of the same type then the "conversion" and assignment will be simpler

Comment: So If ive understood correctly I need both assignment and conversion?

Comment: note that a constructor that is not `explicit` is called a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). So yes, thats what Alan is suggesting, constructor and assignment

Comment: I suspect that having each different-sized `BigInt` being a different type will lead to many more headaches.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Unfortunately this was mandated in the specifications for this assignment.